# Using facebook SDK for php for an FQL query?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I would like to know how to use the following fql query to get a single message from my facebook inbox using facebook sdk for php (or another way if it's possible )

**https://graph.facebook.com//fql?q=SELECT+body+FROM+message+WHERE++mssage_id="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXX"&access_token=...**

(returns a JSON result)

OR

**https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT+body+FROM+message+WHERE+message_id="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXX"&access_token=...**

(returns an XML result)

both methods need an access token for a **read_mailbox** permission. All i need is to get the result using php. Any help ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most flexible way is to use the `api` method of the PHP SDK. The [Facebook documentation site has examples of this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/).

If you already have an access token, this code will get you the data into a php array:

```
<?php
$query = 'SELECT body FROM message WHERE message_id = "?????????????_??"';
$token = '????';
$result = json_decode( file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=' . 
    urlencode($query) . '&access_token=' . $token) );
printf('<pre>%s</pre>', print_r($result, true) );
```

Yes you need an access token for this. If you're trying to read the mailbox of a random user, you need an app, and you'll have to follow one of the [authentication workflows](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) to get them to log into your app and give you the `read_mailbox` permission.

Comment: Well, i am trying to read my own inbox, i have the right access token with read_mailbox permission. It's just that the file_get_contents function never worked for me before with facebook, just like the little code example you gave.

Comment: How does it not work? You should at least be getting an error back.

Comment: returns nothing at all, blank !

You can try

Comment: @cpilko, why’re you talking about “using the API method of the PHP SDK” at first, and then explicitly _don’t_ use it in your sample code, but file_get_contents instead? FQL queries work perfectly fine using Facebook::api().

Comment: @CBroe: A solution with Facebook::api(), requires more prerequisites on the OP's part, which I'm not sure he is ready to follow. I've linked do the docs if he's ready to follow that path. With the OP's original assumption of a known `message_id` and `access_token`, `file_get_contents` gives a minimal viable solution. I posted a live example using the above code to show that it indeed works (which I've since deleted).

Comment: OK, I was just wondering why you were “praising” the SDK first, and then not following up on that in your code sample :-) For me personally, I like to use the SDK wherever possible, since file_get_contents + Facebook API is a combination that can be quite hard to debug – Facebook likes to answer requests with HTTP status codes like 400 if something went wrong (f.e. access-token wise), but file_get_contents under normal circumstances just shows a warning and not the actual body of the HTTP response, so you’re left in the dark about what really went wrong. […]

Comment: [Cont.] I know you can work around this by giving file_get_contents a stream context parameter with the HTTP stream context option _ignore_errors_ set … but that’s even more complex for a beginner. The SDK throws straight exceptions, which are (most of the time) able to point you in the right direction when looking for an error’s reason.

Comment: True, but how do you know the OP isn't like [this one](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11943607/facebook-api-and-fql-qry-post-to-all-my-friends)? Minimum viable answers, in my mind, meet the spirit of Stack Exchange, even if the code isn't optimal.